# How to register afterMarshal in CakePHP 4.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I noticed that there is new afterMarshal event in 4.1.

Where to put it? In Table model? And how?

I want to do some work with results every time it's loaded.

Thanks for help

Comment: Every time what is loaded? Do you mean every time you read a record from the database? That's not what `afterMarshal` is for. Typically, any extra "work" people need to do on entities they load is instead best handled by adding accessors.

Comment: Or https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce

Answer (score 0):

**For Encryption and Decryption through model in 'CAKEPHP 4'**

```
public $encryptedFields = ['first_name','last_name'];


 public function beforeSave($event,  $entity,  $options)
{
    foreach($this->encryptedFields as $fieldName)
    {            if($entity->has($fieldName))
        {         $entity->set($fieldName, encodeBeforeSave($entity->get($fieldName)));}
    }        return true;
}

public function beforeFind( $event,  $query,  $options)
{        $query->formatResults(
        function ($results)
        {                return $results->map(function ($row){
                foreach($this->encryptedFields as $fieldName) 
                {
                    if(isset($row[$fieldName]) && !empty($row[$fieldName]) ) 
                    {
                        $row[$fieldName] = decodeBeforefind($row[$fieldName]);
                    }
                }
                return $row;
            });
        }
    );  
}
```